# The argument type 'Uri' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, uri

i would like to know why flutter gives this error.  I have tried parsing as a String but that has not helped i have also tried Uri.http but with no avail

```
callbackUrl: Uri("http://ip_address:8080/signin"),
```

Answer (score 2):

To parse it will be

```dart
Uri.parse("http://ip_address:8080/signin");
```

Also The error message says, you need to pass string instead of Uri.

Do it like

```dart
callbackUrl:"http://ip_address:8080/signin",
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using only a string

```dart
callbackUrl: "http://ip_address:8080/signin",
```

The error says that you should be passing a string but you are passing a uri